# Find first "inf" (fixed extension) file in zip

Tags: python

I have zip file with N files in root (no subdirs).
Using `zipfile`, how to get name of first .inf file in zip? (e.g. it may be "info.inf".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

archive= ZipFile('path/to/zipfile.zip')
print [info.filename for info in archive.filelist if info.filename.endswith('.inf')][0]
```

Comment: This creates an unnecessary array of strings; for a large zip file it'd be better to loop over the `filelist` and stop after the first instance.

Comment: Inf filelist is small. Usually 2-3 inf's.

Comment: Fair enough, it will still loop through every file in the archive though, so will be slower if there are a lot of other files. Probably not enough to be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

From the Python docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html:

> ZipFile.namelist()
>
> Return a list of archive members by name.

So just iterate on that list and check if an entry `.endswith(".inf")`.

Note that you might also have to care about case-sensitivity.

Example snippet:

```
>>> archive = zipfile.ZipFile("path/to/archive")
>>> for filename in archive.namelist():
...     if filename.endswith(".inf"):
...         print "Found .inf file: " + filename
...         break
```

Comment: different to your idea != incorrect. Your version wouldn't run, you need to remove the `i.` in the print statement.

Comment: I just noticed the mistake and fixed it. But in my opinion it made no sense adding an example that uses `filelist` in an answer that suggests using `namelist()`.

Comment: Fair point, I guess I should read the answer more thoroughly. I'd just tried it using filelist so used that in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('path/to/archive.zip') as archive:
    print next((fn for fn in archive.namelist() if fn.endswith('.inf')), None)
```

prints `None` if such a file is not contained.